# Eland - TypeError: count() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query'

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, elasticsearch, eland

I'm trying to get my ES index as a dataframe using the Eland API in Python.
However, i'm getting a typerror.

```
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=["http://1.1.1.1:9100"], send_get_body_as='POST', http_auth=('es-automation',
                                                                                            'my_password'))
    
    import eland as ed
    ed.DataFrame(es, es_index_pattern='es_index')
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/shivamenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~/shivamenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    392                         if cls is not object \
    393                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 394                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    395 
    396             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~/shivamenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    698     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    699     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 700     output = repr(obj)
    701     lines = output.splitlines()
    702     with p.group():

~/shivamenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eland/dataframe.py in __repr__(self)
    492         min_rows = pd.get_option("display.min_rows")
    493 
--> 494         if max_rows and len(self) > max_rows:
    495             max_rows = min_rows
    496 

~/shivamenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eland/ndframe.py in __len__(self)
    185             Returns an integer length of the DataFrame object.
    186         """
--> 187         return len(self.index)
    188 
    189     def _es_info(self, buf: TextIO) -> None:

~/shivamenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eland/index.py in __len__(self)
     80 
     81     def __len__(self) -> int:
---> 82         return self._query_compiler._index_count()
     83 
     84     # Make iterable

~/shivamenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eland/query_compiler.py in _index_count(self)
    358             Count of docs where index_field exists
    359         """
--> 360         return self._operations.index_count(self, self.index.es_index_field)
    361 
    362     def _index_matches_count(self, items: List[Any]) -> int:

~/shivamenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eland/operations.py in index_count(self, query_compiler, field)
   1273 
   1274         count: int = query_compiler._client.count(
-> 1275             index=query_compiler._index_pattern, **body.to_count_body()
   1276         )["count"]
   1277         return count

~/shivamenv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py in _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     99                 if p in kwargs:
    100                     params[p] = kwargs.pop(p)
--> 101             return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
    102 
    103         return _wrapped

TypeError: count() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query'
```

What's going wrong here? I tried with various indices - still the same issue.

My versions

eland==8.0.0

elastic-transport==8.0.1

elasticsearch==6.8.2

elasticsearch-dsl==7.4.0

elasticsearch7==7.17.0

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading all the supported libs to fit your ES server version (ealsticsearch==7.16; eland==7.16; pandas==1.2.x ...)